# XML - There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create derivations by restriction in an XML Schema, but I cannot get it to work. I have read that when we use restriction and not extension, we are obliged to re-write the contents of the base from where we derive from and I think I have done that, but I can't find what is the issue.

**Validation Errors:**

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 60, 41: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 60; columnNumber: 41; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.
Error - Line 60, 41: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 60; columnNumber: 41; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'seminarType'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.
Error - Line 104, 37: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 104; columnNumber: 37; rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.
Error - Line 104, 37: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 104; columnNumber: 37; derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'labType'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.
```

**XSD Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  targetNamespace="schedule"
                  xmlns="schedule"
                  elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="Event" type="eventType"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="eventType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Lecture" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="9">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Day">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="Monday"/>
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="Tuesday"/>
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="Wednesday"/>
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="Thursday"/>
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="Friday"/>
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="Saturday"/>
                                    <xsd:enumeration value="Sunday"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="Time">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                    <xsd:length value="11"/>
                                    <xsd:pattern value="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"/>
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="Classroom" use="required">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="7"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:attribute>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="lessonType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="eventType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Professor" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="seminarType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="eventType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Lecture" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="9">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="Day">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Monday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Tuesday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Wednesday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Thursday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Friday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Saturday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Sunday"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="Time">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:length value="11"/>
                                            <xsd:pattern value="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:attribute name="Classroom" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="7"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="labType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="eventType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Lecture" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="9">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="Day">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Monday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Tuesday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Wednesday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Thursday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Friday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Saturday"/>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Sunday"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="Time">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:length value="11"/>
                                            <xsd:pattern value="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:attribute name="Classroom" use="required">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="7"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:attribute>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the complex type for the Lecture element cannot be derived from the eventType because the Lecture element is locally defined and has unrelated types as well as the other simple types Day and Time. The relevant place in the specification is:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#rcase-NameAndTypeOK 
3.2.5 R's {type definition} is validly derived given {extension, list, union} from B's {type definition} as defined by Type Derivation OK (Complex) (Â§3.4.6) or Type Derivation OK (Simple) (Â§3.14.6), as appropriate. 
Note: The above constraint on {type definition} means that in deriving a type by restriction, any contained type definitions must themselves be explicitly derived by restriction from the corresponding type definitions in the base definition, or be one of the member types of a corresponding union.

Thus, you can solve this problem if you make base types for necessary elements.

I have attached the fixed solution below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="schedule" xmlns="schedule"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="Event" type="eventType"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="eventType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Lecture" type="lecture" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="9"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="lecture">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Day" type="day"/>
      <xsd:element name="Time" type="time"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="Classroom" type="classroom" use="required"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="lessonType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="eventType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Professor" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="seminarType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="eventType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="Lecture" type="lecture" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="9"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="labType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="eventType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="Lecture" type="lecture" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="9"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="day">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="Monday"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Tuesday"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Wednesday"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Thursday"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Friday"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Saturday"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Sunday"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="time">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:length value="11"/>
      <xsd:pattern value="[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]-[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="classroom">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:maxLength value="7"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

When one schema processor gives unhelpful messages, it's often a good idea to try another schema processor to see if it does any better. In this case Saxon-EE gives the diagnostics:

> Error on line 60 of test.xsd:   The content model of the complex type
>   seminarType is not a valid restriction of the   content model of the
>   type eventType. Definition of element Lecture differs between the  restricted type and the base type. Type of element in restricted
>   content model is not   validly derived from the type of the
>   corresponding element in base content model
>
> Error on line 104 of test.xsd:   The content model of the complex type
>   labType is not a valid restriction of the content   model of the type
>   eventType. Definition of element Lecture differs between the
>   restricted   type and the base type. Type of element in restricted
>   content model is not validly derived   from the type of the
>   corresponding element in base content model

So this points to "Lecture" as the offending particle. The specific issue is that in the restricted type, Lecture must not only have a definition which logically allows a subset of what Lecture allows in the base type, it must actually be defined as a subtype of the corresponding type. Of course that's impossible to do if (as here) the type of Lecture in the base type is anonymous.